# Turn-based Multiplayer Game not finish

Tags: android

My logic is the first player creates a game and takes his turn. The second player takes his turn and ends the match with finish().

```
Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.finishMatch(getApiClient(), mMatch.getMatchId(),
                mTurnData.persist(), creatorResult, opponentResult)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult result) {
                        processResult(result);
                    }
                });
```

The first user gets the status that it is now his turn now in the Play Games built-in inbox.

```
match.getStatus() == MATCH_STATUS_COMPLETE
```

but match.getTurnStatus() is not MATCH_TURN_STATUS_COMPLETE

How do I truly end a game? The first user should see the winner after player 2 finished the game.

the sample code assumes that the finish has to be called for all players. Is this the only possible way? player one gets the notification that it is his turn along with game is over. That is irritating.

```
        // Note that in this state, you must still call "Finish" yourself,
        // so we allow this to continue.
        showWarning("Complete!",
                "This game is over; someone finished it!  You can only finish it now.");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think is a bug!

I find a workaround:

You can check if the status is MATCH_COMPLETED and call the finishMatch for the first user on the onTurnBasedMatchReceived !

This workaround set the MATCH_TURN_STATUS to complete and the first user see the match completed with the correct result.

Like this:

```
 @Override
public void onTurnBasedMatchReceived(TurnBasedMatch match) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "A match was updated.", TOAST_DELAY).show();

    if (match.getStatus()==2){
     Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.finishMatch(mGoogleApiClient, mMatch.getMatchId())
     .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult>() {
         @Override
         public void onResult(TurnBasedMultiplayer.UpdateMatchResult result) {
             processResult(result);
         }
     });
    }
```

The int 2 is the MATCH_STATUS_COMPLETED.
This work good for me, but is only a workaround, I send a bug report to google...
You can see it here:
https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/detail?id=191&thanks=191&ts=1414438242